# User fields that are visible, but can't be manually edited

Tags: 7, entities

I have a web service that will be automatically populating certain attributes of a user's profile.

I am creating my fields via field api when the module is installed. I want all of the fields to be visible when editing the user profile, and some of these fields will be visible publicly as well.

My current plan is to form_alter my away around the issue, but I was wondering if someone has an alternate approach they would take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the hooks used from the field API, there is [hook_field_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7), which allows to define which users has access to a field when the entity is being viewed, or when the entity is being edited.

```
function mymodule_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_of_interest' && $op == 'edit') {
    return user_access('edit field of interest', $account);
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

There is also a module that uses that hook: [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions).

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes
> - Role-based field permissions allowing different viewing patterned based on what access the user has
> - Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on who the entity owner is
> - Permissions for each field are not enabled by default. Instead, administrators can enable these permissions explicitly for the fields where this feature is needed
> - Field permissions overview